# How Static function in C reduce memory footprints?

Tags: c

I've recently learned that declare functions or/and variables as static can reduce footprints, but I can't figured out why. Most article online focus on the scope and readability but not mentioned any benefit about memory allocation. Does "static" really improve performance?

Comment: Impossible to answer generally. Can be yes, can be no, can be doesn't matter, can be "can be".

Comment: First it'd be nice to know *whether* static functions reduce memory footprint. What's your evidence?

Comment: From where you learnt this?

Comment: I learned this from a training doc in my company. I'm wondering whether it's correct or not since I can't find any information on the web. I think the closest information is http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2008/12/efficient-c-tips-5-make-local-functions-static/ , started from "I’d like to give you another reason – it can lead to much more efficient code"

Answer (score 1):

The `static` keyword is primarily about *semantics,* not about *performance.* If you want a variable that persists through multiple calls of the same function, declare it as `static`. If you don't want that, don't declare it as `static`. That said, static variables have a performance benefit, which is that they are only initialized once instead of every time the function is called. In other cases, static variables are slower as they are more likely to not be in the cache. Automatic variables are usually always cached as they are typically allocated on the stack, which is generally a hot area, caching-wise. For this reason, you should make lookup tables or constant variables `static` unless there is a special reason not to (e.g. some people use automatic constant variables as a token to pass to another function).

For functions, the same thing applies: Make a function `static` when you don't want to call it from other translation units. You should most definitely make all functions `static` for which this applies. On ABIs that need to preserve the ability for *symbol interposition* (i.e. the ability to exchange at load time the definition of a global symbol), compilers can only inline static functions. Also, the compiler can remove unused static functions from the binary. This is only possible if the entire translation unit is unused when the function is not static.

Answer (score -1):

Whether using a `static` variable would improve efficiency depends on
many things, including the usage of the variable and the hardware
architecture of your processor. The `C` standard does not specify this.

If you need the variable to retain its value between one call of the
function and the next, it must have static storage duration.
Otherwise the only way to find out for sure is to code it both ways
and do timing tests.